# How to make a local html file with node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have started to make games with Typescript, but the problem is when I try to build it then it needs to run on a Server. Because of this I can't make an offline game with Node.js and TypeScript.

Any help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a server on localhost. The code would be something like this:

```
import http from 'http'
const PORT = 13579 // any 1024~65535 number
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // do something
});
server.listen(PORT, '127.0.0.1');
```

Then go to `http://localhost:<PORT value>`

Or use [electron](https://electronjs.org) to create a cross platform native app.

Comment: but electron creates huge apps
Also , I am planning to distribute to people who don't have node.js

Comment: Then you can use [pkg](https://npmjs.com/pkg). Install it with `npm i -g pkg`, create `pkg` property in `package.json`, set `scripts` property inside it with an array of the server codes(something like `['src/**/*.js']`), set `assets` property with asset files(client js, html, etc). Then run `pkg .` to create executable for windows, macos and linux. @ADRISHKUMARDE

Comment: I am using windows, will it create problem with the macos signing

Comment: @ADRISHKUMARDE on intel mac it doesn't matter. (Still have to right click app and click open first time)

Comment: but on other macs?

Comment: @ADRISHKUMARDE If you have an Apple Silicon Mac, open xcode, go to preferences, and sign in with your apple id. It automatically creates an ad-hoc cert which is capable of running your app in Apple Silicon Mac. Or you can't create one for Apple sillicon mac.